# Function error in c++

Tags: c++, function

I'm studying functions in c++ form a book called "jumping to c++" and there are a problem exercise that is create a calculator and I need make the arithmetic operation in separate functions, sound easy and I think I did it 90% good, the program gives me the correct answer but with some random numbers.

the code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a, b;

int sum()
{

       return a + b;

}

int subs()
{

    return a - b;

}

int div()
{

    return a / b;

}

int mult()
{

    return a * b;

}

int ask()
{

    cout << "Give me the first number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "\nGive me the second number: ";
    cin >> b;

}

int main()
{

    int opcion;

    cout << "1. Sum \n2. Substraction \n3. Division \n4. Multiplication \n\nChoose one option from above: \n\n";
    cin >> opcion;

    if(opcion == 1)
    {

        cout << ask();

        cout << "The result is: " <<sum() <<"\n\n";

    } else if (opcion == 2)
      {

          cout << ask();

          cout << "The result is: " << subs() <<"\n\n";

      }else if (opcion == 3)
        {

            cout <<ask();

            cout << "The result is: " << div() <<"\n\n";

        }else if(opcion == 4)
         {

            cout << ask();

             cout << "The result is: " << mult() <<"\n\n";

         }else
            {

                cout << "Error.\n\n";

            }

    system("pause");

}
```

and this is the "error/bug/whatever"

```
1. Sum
2. Substraction
3. Division
4. Multiplication

Choose one option from above:

4
Give me the first number: 5

Give me the second number: 5
1878005856The result is: 25

Press any key to continue . . .
```

notice the error before of "The result is:"

appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: make `ask()` return `void` and don't do `cout << ask();`. Just do `ask();`

Comment: And make sure you enable and read compiler warnings - there should be one saying that `ask()` doesn't return anything although declared to return an `int`.

Comment: I suggest : (1) use a switch instead of a long chain of if/else, it is more readable (2) remove using namespace std and use std::cin (3) use std::endl to close the output stream (4) main is a function as well like the others so you should add return 0; (it signals that the program terminated with no errors). These are good advices to keep in mind if you are starting with c++

Comment: thanks for helping and the advices, appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ask()` does not return anything so it should be a void. Also, you do not need to do `cout << ask();` since `ask()` already does the printing inside of it and it is a void (now) so it can't be printed.

Here is the code with the modifications, see comments with **** in front for changes:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a, b;

int sum() {
  return a + b;
}

int subs() {
  return a - b;
}

int div() {
  return a / b;
}

int mult() {
  return a * b;
}

void ask() { // **** Changed to void here
  cout << "Give me the first number: ";
  cin >> a;
  cout << "\nGive me the second number: ";
  cin >> b;
}

int main() {
  int opcion;

  cout << "1. Sum \n2. Substraction \n3. Division \n4. Multiplication \n\nChoose one option from above: \n\n";
  cin >> opcion;

  if (opcion == 1) {
    ask(); // **** Removed cout << 
    cout << "The result is: " << sum() << "\n\n";
  } else if (opcion == 2) {
    ask(); // **** Removed cout << 
    cout << "The result is: " << subs() << "\n\n";
  } else if (opcion == 3) {
    ask(); // **** Removed cout << 
    cout << "The result is: " << div() << "\n\n";
  } else if (opcion == 4) {
    ask(); // **** Removed cout << 
    cout << "The result is: " << mult() << "\n\n";
  } else {
    cout << "Error.\n\n";
  }
  system("pause");
}
```

You can try it [here](http://cpp.sh/3ryzx)

The random number was caused by you doing `cout << ask();` even though you had not returned anything.

As aschepler pointed out "make sure you enable and read compiler warnings - there should be one saying that ask() doesn't return anything although declared to return an int."

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `int ask()` function.
It must return int value which you are writing to console with `cout << ask();`

The answer above won't work because you cannot write `void` to cout.

Since you do not return a value then a random number retruned. My compiler marks that as an error.

Replace type of ask function:

```
void ask()
{
    cout << "Give me the first number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "\nGive me the second number: ";
    cin >> b;
}
```

Then replace `cout << ask();` in every if statement with just `ask();`

Like this:

```
if (opcion == 1)
    {
        ask();
        cout << "The result is: " << sum() << "\n\n";
    }
    else if (opcion == 2)
    {
        ask();
        cout << "The result is: " << subs() << "\n\n";

    }
    else if (opcion == 3) ...
```

Consider checking if b==0 in case of devision operation. Or your program will crash if u try to devide by zero.

Answer (score 0):

this function is returning a random integer. convert it to void

```
int ask()
{
    cout << "Give me the first number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "\nGive me the second number: ";
    cin >> b;

}
```

new

```
void ask()
{
    cout << "Give me the first number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "\nGive me the second number: ";
    cin >> b;

}
```